# How to dynamically add to comboboxes from infinitely nested dictionary?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, recursion

I've got a infinitely nested dictionary.
The data is coming from a json and is read in as Dictionary<string, dynamic>. The dynamic can then have infinite nesting. Imagine it being as such:

```
"Data1":
{         
   "config":
   {
       "V": 68,
       "Y": 98,
   }

   "Limit":
   {
   }

   "Measures":
   {
       "12pm": 5,
       "1pm": 6,
       "2pm": 41,
       "3pm": 35,
   }
}
"Data2":
{         
   "config":
   {
       "V": 68,
       "Y": 98,
   }

   "Limit":
   {
       "12pm": 10,
       "1pm": 66,
       "2pm": 100,
       "3pm": 22,
   }

   "Measures":
   {
       "Monday":
       {
           "12pm": 4,
           "1pm": 6,
           "2pm": 21,
           "3pm": 66,
       },
       "Tuesday"
       {
           "12pm": 2,
           "1pm": 4,
           "2pm": 11,
           "3pm": 56,
        }       
   }
}
```

The first level would be the keys Data1, Data2
So in combobox1 there are two entries: Data1, and Data2.
Once something has been selected in combobox1. Combobox2 would get filled with the keys under that entry.
When combobox2 has been selected, combobox3 will be all keys keys under combobox2 entry. etc etc.

However I do not know how long the nesting goes on for. For example, you can see under Data1[Measures] there is only one dictionary and no more nesting. So to get to that entry you would select:
Combobox1 = Data1
Combobox2 = Measures
Combobox3 then contains : 12pm, 1pm, 2pm and 3pm

However in the second data entry Data2. There is one additional level of nesting so to get to the values it would be
Combobox1:Data2
Combobox2: Measures
Combobox3: Monday (or Tuesday)
and combobox4 would now have the values there available for selection.

How would I go about filling these dynamically created comboboxes depending on how deep the nesting goes?
As this is an example this is only 3-4 levels deep. However imagine this goes for 20 levels deep. I have currently done this with A LOT of foreach loops which seems tedious. Is there any way to deal with this using recursion or similar?

Comment: a) do you know how to make a ComboBox programmatically? b) do you know about recursion?

Comment: Well yes I am aware of both. However my knowledge is limited when it comes to this level of programming. Very new to recursion so getting into the mindset of it is where I get stuck